# show on a button number that show new mesege Asp.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I display a button that shows the number of incoming messages. 
when a new row is enter from the service to the database the number on the button will be updated?
Maybe Should Do the update with the server?

Do you have any idea?

tnx,
Riva

Comment: Can you post some sample code etc., showing what exactly you are trying to do? For more details : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i don't have an idea how to implement it but it's have to be like[link]https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-mail-checker/mihcahmgecmbnbcchbopgniflfhgnkff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use ajax to auto reload partial page or database events.
Easy solution would be ajax. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb398890(v=vs.100).aspx" > help